# App Store publish app for iPad and update for iPhone later

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, app-store

So i want to publish my app on the App Store but the app is only working on iPad's now. Can i upload the version 1.0 with the "Devices" option set on iPad and when i want to update the new version 1.1 with "Devices" set to Universal. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes that is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. I see no reason why not.

Comment: Thanks sir , that was all i had to know.

Comment: You're welcome. The opposite situation when you reduce the list of available device types is dangerous: the app may be easily rejected by review team.